# OpenSSL always shows "unsupported" for all subjectAltName "otherName" UTF8 values

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

It seems like OpenSSL is broken when trying to read back *subjectAltName/otherName/UTF8* values that were written by itself:

The relevant *openssl.cnf* configuration (using an official but random OID):

```
[alt_names]
DNS.1   = www.foo.com
DNS.2   = www.bar.org
IP.1    = 192.168.1.1
IP.2    = 192.168.69.144
email = email@me

otherName = 1.3.6.1.4.1.1;UTF8:some other identifier
```

A sample from the dump of a CSR generated from this config:

```
            TLS Web Server Authentication
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            DNS:www.foo.com, DNS:www.bar.org, IP Address:192.168.1.1, IP Address:192.168.69.144, email:email@me, othername:<unsupported>
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    6f:4a:1d:8f:43:7e:4d:d1:0c:7e:05:9d:1f:f0:98:b1:69:cf:
```

Can someone indicate whether I'm doing something wrong? This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, you will have to locate the "OCTET STRING" line just below the "OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Alternative Name" line then `strparse`:

```
# print section offset via
openssl asn1parse -in yourcert.pem
# parse otherName from "OCTET STRING" 
openssl asn1parse -in yourcert.pem -strparse <offset>
```

Comment: I added `-dump` to the first command along with `-strictpem` and it gave the text equivalent dump along side the hex output for the whole cert.

Answer (score 3):

## Probably still unsupported. Try asn1parse.

The `<unsupported>` output was the regular result in 2010. My guess: this is still the case.

An OpenSSL dev said this on [the mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.openssl.user/37211/focus=37217) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/KZYqh).):

Steven Hensen, 2010-01-02:

> Currently OpenSSL doesn't display any otherName values. It can't know the
>   precise meaning of that field in general because the format could be totally
>   arbitrary. At best it could asn1parse the contents.

And if you use `openssl asn1parse` on the file to find the offset of the `:X509v3 Subject Alternative Name` section and then use the `-strparse` option with that offset, then `otherName` will in fact be displayed.